# Google Zeitgeist 2011 visualization

Tags: html, user-interface, canvas, visualization, user-experience

While admiring the beautiful graphics and animations of the [2011 Zeitgeist](http://www.googlezeitgeist.com/en/top-lists/global/fastest-rising) I was wondering if the visualization are custom made or based from an available library or project.

[image]

**Do you know is there a library or project for making similar HTML(5) visualization?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built this from scratch after I saw the Google zeitgeist app. http://hsivaram.com/tech/2012/01/09/demo-data-visualization-inspired-by-google-zeitgeist-2011/

Answer (score 1):

seems to be javascript-based. If you open up the web inspector you can see that it uses a libs.js file along with scripts.js under the 'zeitgeist' category.

Of course, it also uses [Keanu](https://github.com/wambotron/Keanu) and JQuery.

The art is probably custom.